# Sorting a filtered list in ascending/descending order in django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I have created an Employee management system using Django. I have done a filtering method in it and is based on a choice selected from a drop down menu and a text input. the filtering is working fine. On the first page it gives the entire employee list which can be shown in both ascending and descending order. On the same page is given the filtering method. The filtered data is shown in another page. Now i want to give a button on the filtered data page, clicking on that button shows the data in ascending/descending. I have written a separate function for ascending and descending in views for the full employee listing. How can it be used for this functionality. I will paste my code here. Please help me to find a solution as i am new to django programming.
I have given 2 separate images for ascending and descending.I want it this way: Clicking on 1 image lists in ascending order; and clicking on other image lists it in descending order.

**Filter()**

```
def filter(request):
    val3='' 
    if request.GET.has_key('choices'):
        val2=request.GET.get('choices')
    if request.GET.has_key('textField'):
        val3=request.GET.get('textField')
    if request.POST:
        val2=request.POST.get('choices')    
        val3=request.POST.get('textField')
    if val2=='Designation':                
        newData = EmployeeDetails.objects.filter(designation=val3) 
        flag=True 
    elif val2=='Name':
        newData = EmployeeDetails.objects.filter(userName__icontains=val3)
        flag=True 
    elif val2=='EmployeeID':
        newData = EmployeeDetails.objects.filter(employeeID=val3)  
        flag=True       
    elif val2=='Project':
        newData = EmployeeDetails.objects.filter(project=val3)   
        flag=True   
    elif val2=='DateOfJoin':
        newData = EmployeeDetails.objects.filter(dateOfJoin=val3) 
        flag=True       
    else:
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/employeeList/')    
    #tableList = EmployeeDetails.objects.all()
    paginator = Paginator(newData, 10)    
    try:
         page = int(request.GET.get('page', '1'))
    except ValueError:
        page = 1
    try:
        contacts = paginator.page(page)
    except (EmptyPage, InvalidPage):
        contacts = paginator.page(0)               
    return render_to_response('filter.html',{'newData':newData,'emp_list': contacts,'val2':val2,'val3':val3,'flag':flag})
```

**filter.html**

```
<div>
Employees List&nbsp;&nbsp;
<a STYLE="text-decoration:none" align=center href="http://10.1.0.90:8080/sortAscend/ "> <img  src="/static/sort_asc.gif " border="1" height="12" /> </a>
<h4 align="left">
{%for data in newData%}
<a STYLE="text-decoration:none" href ="http://10.1.0.90:8080/singleEmployee/{{data.id}}?choices={{val2}}&textField={{val3}}&flag=1 ">
{{ data.userName}}<br>
{%endfor%} 
</h4>
</div>
```

**ascending and descending functions**

```
def sortAscend(request):
    tableList = EmployeeDetails.objects.all().order_by('userName')
    paginator = Paginator(tableList, 12)    
    try:
         page = int(request.GET.get('page', '1'))
    except ValueError:
        page = 1
    try:
        contacts = paginator.page(page)
    except (EmptyPage, InvalidPage):
        contacts = paginator.page(0)
    return render_to_response('sortAscend.html', {'emp_list': contacts})

#Method for listing the employees in descending order
def sortDescend(request):
    tableList = EmployeeDetails.objects.all().order_by('-userName')
    paginator = Paginator(tableList, 12)    
    try:
         page = int(request.GET.get('page', '1'))
    except ValueError:
        page = 1
    try:
        contacts = paginator.page(page)
    except (EmptyPage, InvalidPage):
        contacts = paginator.page(0)
    return render_to_response('sortDescend.html', {'emp_list': contacts})
```

**sortAscending.html**

```
{%for emp in emp_list.object_list%}
    <tr> <td><a STYLE="text-decoration:none" href ="http://10.1.0.90:8080/singleEmployee/{{emp.id}} "> {{ emp.userName }} </a></td> </tr><td>
{%endfor%}
```

Comment: If you want table ordering sorted on the fly, without generating a new page, look into JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another alternative to handling sorting in the view level is to do it on the templates. For this reason, you might want to checkout [jquery tablesorter](http://tablesorter.com/docs/) (since you are using a table in the display as well). It handles sorting in ascending/descending order.

So if you have the results after filtering that is ready to be displayed to a page, say filtered_results.html, you can do it like this.

```
<!-- filtered_results.html -->
<head>
   ...
   <script type="text/javascript" src="/path/to/jquery-latest.js"></script> 
   <script type="text/javascript" src="/path/to/jquery.tablesorter.js"></script> 
   <script type="text/javascript">
       $(document).ready(function() {
           $("#myTable").tablesorter();
       });
   </script>
</head>
<body>
    <table id="myTable">
        <thead><tr><th>Some-Label</th></tr></thead>
        <tbody>
        {% for emp in emp_list.object_list %}
            <tr><td><a href="http://10.1.0.90:8080/singleEmployee/{{emp.id}}">{{emp.userName}}</a></td></tr>
        {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
```

Clicking on the cell of 'Some-Label' will toggle the sorting in ascending/descending order.

Furthermore, it has a plugin for handling pagination. Check out this [link](http://tablesorter.com/docs/example-pager.html) for the demo.

Comment: that was perfect for my need..Thanks a lot gladys

Comment: i have a more doubt.. i gave it like this: " <thead><tr><th>Filtered Employee List  <input type="image" src="/static/sort_desc.gif " height="12" name="sortDescend"> </th></tr></thead> " , ie just 1 image does both the function. can we make it like it shows an uparrow first. on clicking it shows the list in ascending order, and the image changes to down arrow. on clicking it displays in descending order. ?

Comment: I find it confusing. The arrow in the header indicate how the column is sorted, that's why it displays a down-arrow when sorted in descending order, and an up otherwise. You want to reverse it? Its not elegant but it will work if you interchange the arrow images that it uses, ie. rename sort_desc.gif to sort_asc.gif and vice versa.

Comment: no..thats not i meant..i meant i need to show two arrows(image)..now just 1 image is given, so for both ascending and descending sorting. there is no image change.But i wanted to show an up arrow for ascending and when i click again it should change image to down arrow and descending fucntionaliy should work. This is how i given the image now :

Comment: <table id="myTable">
        <thead><tr><th>Filtered Employee List  <input type="image" src="/static/sort_asc.gif " height="12" name="sortAscend"> </th></tr></thead>
        <tbody>
        {% for emp in emp_list.object_list %}
            <tr><td><a href="http://10.1.0.90:8080/singleEmployee/{{emp.id}}?choices={{val2}}&textField={{val3}}&flag=True ">{{emp.userName}}</a></td></tr>
        {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
    </table>

Comment: I got it right..I didnt included the css class in my code before..when i added that to the page, it works just fine..thanks a lot gladys

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I get the question, but if you want to apply the sorting to the filtered objects, you might want to add some sort of caching (different from django's builtin caching), that stores the filtered queryset and sort that. Or you can pass the filter option around using django's session management and redo the sorting query.  This would require to refactor filter so the if/elif chain is independant of that view and returns the filtered queryset.

ex:

```
   def filterHandler(request):
     val3='' 
     if request.GET.has_key('choices'):
        val2=request.GET.get('choices')
     if request.GET.has_key('textField'):
        val3=request.GET.get('textField')
     if request.POST:
        val2=request.POST.get('choices')    
        val3=request.POST.get('textField')
     newData , flag = filter(val2, val3)
     if newData is None:
       return HttpResponseRedirect('/employeeList/')    
     #tableList = EmployeeDetails.objects.all()
     paginator = Paginator(newData, 10)    
     try:
         page = int(request.GET.get('page', '1'))
     except ValueError:
        page = 1
     try:
        contacts = paginator.page(page)
     except (EmptyPage, InvalidPage):
        contacts = paginator.page(0)

     request.session['val2'] = val2
     request.session['val3'] = val3              
     return render_to_response('filter.html',{'newData':newData,'emp_list': contacts,'val2':val2,'val3':val3,'flag':flag})    

    def filter(val2, val3):
      newData = None
      flag = False
      if val2=='Designation':                
        newData = EmployeeDetails.objects.filter(designation=val3) 
        flag=True 
      elif val2=='Name':
        newData = EmployeeDetails.objects.filter(userName__icontains=val3)
        flag=True 
      elif val2=='EmployeeID':
        newData = EmployeeDetails.objects.filter(employeeID=val3)  
        flag=True       
      elif val2=='Project':
        newData = EmployeeDetails.objects.filter(project=val3)   
        flag=True   
      elif val2=='DateOfJoin':
        newData = EmployeeDetails.objects.filter(dateOfJoin=val3) 
        flag=True       
      return newData, flag
```

Now your sorting methods can get the filter values that was passed originally. Optionally you can add them as get parameters to the views url also.

Comment: trying this i got an error 'global name val2 is not defined' ?

Comment: add a `val2 = ''` where you do val3